# SESSION MERGE new record on changes for specific columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

Let's say my User Database has this record already inserted

```
[id=1, name="GRIZZLY BEAR", age= 20, run_id=49019]
```

The behavior I want upon a new insert is the following:

If primary key value [id] already exists in the DB

- Check to see if there's a change on any column BUT the [run_id]
  column
- If there's a change, merge the changes including the new [run_id] value

If it doesn't exist

- Insert new Record

**Example 1** :
Causing no change in DB record:

```
o = User(id=1, name="GRIZZLY BEAR", age= 20, run_id=49020)
session.merge(o)
```

**Example 2**:
Causing a change in DB record to be `[id=1, name="GRIZZLY BEAR", age= 19, run_id=49020]`

```
o = User(id=1, name="GRIZZLY BEAR", age= 19, run_id=49020)
session.merge(o)
```

SQLAlchemy merge checks for every column so the run_id in the first example will cause an update automatically, which is a behavior I don't want.

Do I have to make my own SQL merge query and execute it using SQLAlchemy or is there a way to use the built-in fn automatically and say detect changes on specific columns.